# Is it possible to use Cache in webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, caching

In my webapplication I have some precalculated values that are stored in Page.Cache. At his moment I have to move this functionality to webservice.

So I need to introduce similiar functionality in webservice - calculate values on first call to web method and store it in Cache.
Is it possible to put some values in Cache (not in Application or Session - I need to purge those values after some time interval) from webservice?

Comment: `not in Application or Session` which cache do you want to use, a new one?

Comment: As you see in answers below - there is something like old, known 'Cache' :)

Comment: Yep if was a question to you, trying to work out what your requirements were. There is the Runtime cache, or you can create your own. You can also use callback expiry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can always access the Cache through the static [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) property, even if you don't have an HttpContext at the moment.

Comment: The easiest way - it is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 6):

In short - yes, you can use caching in web services. You have to choose the correct cache implementation based on service implementation. For example, if you are using ASP.NET web services then you can probably use [ASP.NET Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx) - available via [HttpContext.Current.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx).

If you are using WCF web services then you may need to use other libraries (BTW, ASP.NET web services are obsolete, so I will suggest WCF web services anyway). If WCF services are marked as ASP.NET compatible then ASP.NET infrastructure and its cache will be available. But you have choice to host WCF services w/o ASP.NET integration and in such case, you probably need to look at different caching API - for example, [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching%28VS.100%29.aspx) if you are using .NET 4 (see a [quick tutorial](http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/object-caching----net-4/37) for using in-memory cache) otherwise you may try [Caching Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664753%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(strName, objItem, null,
     DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intMinutes), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration)
```

to cache item for a specified time interval.

Answer (score 1):

Refer [XML Web Service Caching Strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480499.aspx)

It seems to be a bit old but good article. I hope you will be able to find what you are looking for.